# Cant set ID value for a <span> tag inside a <th v-for="" >tag

Tags: html, vue.js, html-table, tooltip, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to set a value of the v-for loop as the ID value of the  tag inside the for loop.

```
 <table class="APPPPTable" style="width:100%;font-size:11px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="heading in tableInfo.columns" class="text-center">
            <span id="heading.field" v-html="heading.label"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
 </table>
```

the "heading.field" has value. But everytime i see the developer tools it is showing the id value of the  as id="heading.field" instead of the "heading.field" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `:id="heading.field"`

Answer (score 3):

`id` of your span is not binding dynamically, you have to use `v-bind:` or `:` to that's id to use it in way what you want:

Look at example:

```
<table class="APPPPTable" style="width:100%;font-size:11px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="heading in tableInfo.columns" class="text-center">
            <span :id="heading.field" v-html="heading.label"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<span id="heading.field">` -> `<span v-bind:id="heading.field">`

```
 <table class="APPPPTable" style="width:100%;font-size:11px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="heading in tableInfo.columns" class="text-center">
            <span v-bind:id="heading.field" v-html="heading.label"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
 </table>
```